# SQL Set value for all records within a group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to use a CASE statement to create another column that sets the value for the column "Type" in a group as Gold if there is a single occurrence of Gold within that group.

I have tried using a CASE Statement with both LAG and LEAD to check if the previous or next row in Type = 'Gold' but it's turning out to be a rather long solution and I have no idea how many rows I would need to check using LAG/LEAD.

This is a sample of the data:

```
Company     Year     Country Type
  A          2018    US       null
  A          2018    US       null      
  A          2019    US       null     
  B          2018    AU       Gold
  B          2019    AU       Black
  B          2019    BR       Gold
  C          2019    FR       Silver
  C          2019    CA       Silver
  C          2019    DE       Gold
```

Expected output:

```
Company      Year    Country Type
  A          2018    US       null
  A          2018    US       null      
  A          2019    US       null     
  B          2018    AU       Gold
  B          2019    AU       Gold
  B          2019    BR       Gold
  C          2019    FR       Gold
  C          2019    CA       Gold
  C          2019    DE       Gold
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `count` analytic function

```
SELECT company,year,country,CASE
     WHEN COUNT(
             CASE WHEN type = 'Gold' THEN 1
            END ) OVER(PARTITION BY company) > 0 THEN 'Gold'
     ELSE type
END AS type
FROM t;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b986ff655b51251c9e63c6d5957f15bb)